# Create table output for specific row ID's that don't match in 3 spreadsheets

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I want to create a VBA script that will output a spreadsheet filled with rows populated with columns from all 3 tables where specified row ID's from each spreadsheet tables do NOT match eachother(all 3). So if Name and Surname were the ID's

```
 Table 1
 Name  | Surname | Age | Date     | Bank Account No.
 John  | Marley  | 23  | 21/07/19 | 25511581125
 Simon | Harvey  | 22  | 04/03/19 | 25513321125

 Table 2
 Name  | Surname | Age | Date     | Gender
 John  | Marley  | 23  | 21/07/19 | Male
 Simon | Harvey  | 22  | 04/03/19 | Male

 Table 3
 Name  | Surname | Age | Date     | Height
 John  | Marley  | 23  | 21/07/19 | 5ft
 Simon | John    | 18  | 21/07/19 | 2ft
```

---

```
 Output

 Name  | Surname | Age | Date     | Bank Account No.
 Simon | Harvey  | 22  | 04/03/19 | 25513321125


 Name  | Surname | Age | Date     | Gender
 Simon | Harvey  | 22  | 04/03/19 | Male


 Name  | Surname | Age | Date     | Height
 Simon | John    | 18  | 21/07/19 | 2ft
```

---

So what I want is an output of every row from every table where the specified ID in the row is NOT found in ALL 3 tables. I hope this makes sense. The ID's specified must be present in exactly all 3 tables. Having an output that will keep a single column where the exact name across all 3 tables are the same would be ideal but not needed.

The reason I've added ADODB as a tag is I understand this will be an easier and much more efficient solution?

I understand it would probably be easier just to remove the ones that do match all 3? Or highlight them or something.

If anyone has any theories as how I should complete this I would love to hear it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range, cell3 As Range
    Dim ID As String
    Dim LastRowG As Long, Times As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

            Set rng1 = .Range("F3:F5")
            Set rng2 = .Range("F9:F11")
            Set rng3 = .Range("F15:F17")

        Times = 0

        For Each cell1 In rng1

            ID = cell1.Value

            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng2, ID) + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng3, ID) < 2 Then

                Times = Times + 1

                LastRowG = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

                If Times = 1 Then
                    .Range("H" & LastRowG + 1).Value = "Name"
                    .Range("I" & LastRowG + 1).Value = "Surname"
                    .Range("J" & LastRowG + 1).Value = "Age"
                    .Range("K" & LastRowG + 1).Value = "Date"
                    .Range("L" & LastRowG + 1).Value = "Bank Account No."
                    .Range("A" & cell1.Row & ":E" & cell1.Row).Copy .Range("H" & LastRowG + 2)
                Else
                    .Range("A" & cell1.Row & ":E" & cell1.Row).Copy .Range("H" & LastRowG + 1)
                End If

            End If

        Next cell1

        Times = 0

        For Each cell2 In rng2

            ID = cell2.Value

            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng1, ID) + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng3, ID) < 2 Then

                Times = Times + 1

                LastRowG = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

                If Times = 1 Then
                    .Range("H" & LastRowG + 2).Value = "Name"
                    .Range("I" & LastRowG + 2).Value = "Surname"
                    .Range("J" & LastRowG + 2).Value = "Age"
                    .Range("K" & LastRowG + 2).Value = "Date"
                    .Range("L" & LastRowG + 2).Value = "Gender"
                    .Range("A" & cell2.Row & ":E" & cell2.Row).Copy .Range("H" & LastRowG + 3)
                Else
                    .Range("A" & cell2.Row & ":E" & cell2.Row).Copy .Range("H" & LastRowG + 1)
                End If

            End If

        Next cell2

        Times = 0

        For Each cell3 In rng3

            ID = cell3.Value

            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng2, ID) + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng1, ID) < 2 Then

                Times = Times + 1

                LastRowG = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

                If Times = 1 Then
                    .Range("H" & LastRowG + 2).Value = "Name"
                    .Range("I" & LastRowG + 2).Value = "Surname"
                    .Range("J" & LastRowG + 2).Value = "Age"
                    .Range("K" & LastRowG + 2).Value = "Date"
                    .Range("L" & LastRowG + 2).Value = "Height"
                    .Range("A" & cell3.Row & ":E" & cell3.Row).Copy .Range("H" & LastRowG + 3)
                Else
                    .Range("A" & cell3.Row & ":E" & cell3.Row).Copy .Range("H" & LastRowG + 1)
                End If

            End If

        Next cell3

    End With

End Sub
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input! I've found a solution using the SQL Query for anyone interested in the future, just needs a bit more tweaking to be complete for 3 tables and returning all 3 tables rows!  

    "SELECT *" _& " FROM [Sheet1$] s1" _  
    & " WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT s2.Name, s2.Surname" _  
                    & " FROM [Sheet2$] s2" _  
                    & " WHERE s1.Name = s2.Name AND s1.Surname = s2.Surname)

Comment: Being that I feel it is still an alternative solution to my problem I'm going to mark it as corrrect.